# Could free speech be absolute?

Tags: law, freedom-of-speech, society

Since the past few days,  I have been spending some time on X (Formerly Twitter). I saw people being openly racist and calling it their "right to free speech". I personally don't give much attention to such types but it has been all over the app recently. Apart from that, there are several handles running secession campaigns against their particular countries, some of them are sharing misinformation on such a large scale that it could create angst amongst the general population.

Politicians, on a regular basis seek to ridicule their opponents with personal attacks. Some people with a religious agenda peddle misinformation against the other group and create a divide between two or more communities. It leads to killing of several innocent people. The murderers get arrested most of the time, but the enablers, who initially caused generally get away in the name of "free speech".

My question therefore is that could free speech really be absolute? Can society really function in black and white? Or such matters should be looked upon with a lens of grey?

Comment: Are you asking whether it _is_ absolute?  _Should be_ absolute?  _Can possibly be_ absolute in some hypothetical society?  _Was ever_ absolute at some point in the past?

Comment: I don't know if it is that objectively answerable here (there is a SE.Philosophy where it might work better).  But it is not that unreasonable to be wondering about this, including *politically*.  Welcome aboard.  And... - to others - notice the *"New contributor"*, be friendly icon?  You know, before you downvote without explanation?

Comment: It is worth noting that during the time period that America became the richest and most powerful nation on Earth, the 1st Amendment did not hinder it from becoming so.

Comment: I think this is a good question to ask... Could be clearer... but this isn't a bad question. Also, I have an answer to this question that should provoke a lot of thought.

Comment: @Questor it's not clear enough. What does absolute mean? What does "really function" mean? Without some sort of limitation this in an invitation to an open ended discussion, not a Q&A. The question should specify what it really wants to know.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I thought the meaning of absolute was pretty clear, it is well defined in the dictionary. Usage here shows a lack of knowledge about freedom of speech in the USA.. because it is not an 'absolute' freedom of speech as there are limitations.

Comment: @Questor I don't understand what the question wants to know about absolute free speech. I could imagine something but that might be something else than what others might imagine. Maybe the question can simply clarify where exactly it sees the problem and what kind of solutions it seeks.

Answer (score 4):

It *might* be possible, but it might also involve redefining "speech".

For example, when a mob boss tells his underling to commit a crime on his behalf, is he just exercising his right to free speech? So only the underling is liable for the crime that was committed, the boss is in the clear.

What if the boss *teaches* the underling how to commit the crime? Is that also just speech?

The general understanding of the right to free speech is that it's about not depriving people of the right to express opinions, even if they're unpopular. But many speech acts are not just making statements, or expressing opinions. They cause actions to occur, and these actions have consequences that may be against the public interest.

When the commander of a firing squad orders "fire!", this directly causes the death of the target of the squad.

Answer (score -2):

No, free speech is never absolute as there are plenty of things that will never be allowed.

Also, free speech only applies to the government and it never applies to a private organization such as twitter/x/facebook and they can remove things for whatever reasons they decide.

[What Does Free Speech Mean?](https://www.uscourts.gov/about-federal-courts/educational-resources/about-educational-outreach/activity-resources/what-does)

> Freedom of speech does not include the right:
>
> To incite imminent lawless action. Brandenburg v. Ohio, 395 U.S. 444
> (1969).
>
> To make or distribute obscene materials. Roth v. United
> States, 354 U.S. 476 (1957).
>
> To burn draft cards as an anti-war
> protest. United States v. O’Brien, 391 U.S. 367 (1968).
>
> To permit
> students to print articles in a school newspaper over the objections
> of the school administration.  Hazelwood School District v. Kuhlmeier,
> 484 U.S. 260 (1988).
>
> Of students to make an obscene speech at a
> school-sponsored event. Bethel School District #43 v. Fraser, 478 U.S.
> 675 (1986).
>
> Of students to advocate illegal drug use at a
> school-sponsored event. Morse v. Frederick, __ U.S. __ (2007).
>
> Disclaimer: These resources are created by the Administrative Office >of the U.S. Courts for use in educational activities only. They may >not reflect the current state of the law, and are not intended to >provide legal advice, guidance on litigation, or commentary on >legislation.

Comment: I don’t know if there is a relevant court case, but it is also worth noting free speech doesn’t protect the right to say something on a platform that doesn’t want you to say it on their platform

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Free speech only applies to the government and it doesn't apply to any private organization. They would be perfectly free to block anyone they choose.;

Comment: I agree with you, I just added my first comment as a footnote because the original question was talking about free speech in the context of twitter

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica I understand but it seems to be needed to be repeated many times that free speech will never apply to a private organization such as twitter/x

Comment: This seems to be an USA centric answer. For example *[freedom of speech] never applies to a private company*. Some countries have laws forbidding private companies from certain policies against freedom of speech.

Comment: @SJuan76 That would apply only to certain types of speech and wouldn't apply to all types though.

Comment: [ObXKCD](https://xkcd.com/1357/)

Comment: @JoeW there is the Public Forum doctrine... but how that applies to the internet (at least in the US) is still up for debate.

Comment: It is not true that it can never apply to private organizations.  It DOES apply to private organizations which own what is legally considered public spaces under certain circumstances.  Various pamphleteering laws were challenged in the mid 20th century because shopping malls became the new public squares, which were publicly owned.  This culminated in SCOTUS decisions that states have the right (but not an obligation) to force private owners of public spaces to open those spaces to unintrusive politicking (such as pamphleteering).

Comment: @wrod Absolute freedom of speech never applies to private organizations, sure there are areas that are protected but those areas are all well defined about what is and isn't allowed.